# Carrying out time calculations with Joda-time?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm stuck on this task. I want to add various hours or minutes to the current time. So  the user presses a button and the `onClick` will pull the current time and then add however many hours and minutes I decide. At the moment I have it adding two hours but I want to be able to add and subtracts around `2 hours` and `14 minutes`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void onClickHere (View v) {

    LocalTime localtime = new LocalTime();
    LocalTime dt = new LocalTime(localtime.getHourOfDay(), localtime.getMinuteOfHour());
    LocalTime twoHoursLater = dt.plusHours(2);

    Text1.setText("Time: " + twoHoursLater);

}
```

Now the code above does part of what I want. It gets the localtime and adds two hours to it. However it shows a lot of extra numbers. Seconds & Milliseconds.

Is there a way for me to only show the hours and minutes?

By calling `getHourOfDay()` and `getMinuteOfHour()` it only pulls the hours and minutes BUT it still shows `00.000` for the seconds and minutes.

So if I pressed the button now it would show `10:58:00.000`. What I would like it to show is `10:58`.

and Eventually being able to add minutes but I think that's another issue, a simpler issue that I can simply take example from already knowing how to add two hours.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
Text1.setText("Time: " + twoHoursLater.toString(formatter));
```

Note: `DateTimeFormatter` is thread safe so you can define it as a `private final static` variable and reuse it instead of creating one instance every time `onClickHere` is called.

Comment: Weird because I did look into that. I think I put it into the wrong place because I was getting Force closes. (I put it above the Localtime() bit). Of course at the time I thought that was correct. Thank you very much it worked perfectly. Will accept answer.